# Java Concurrency Abstraction for Work Queue

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I found myself thinking through solving a concurrency problem too much, which to me indicates there is probably an abstraction to accomplish what I want that I should use instead.

Here is the basic premise:

- I have a queue of data that I can do work on
- Threads can come in and add work to the queue
- There is a high overhead associated with starting and finishing a set of items to work on
- Only one thread can work on the data at a time

I figured the following API would be nice:

- Threads can add work to the queue
- If the data in the queue isn't currently being worked on, invoke a background task to start working
- The background task continues working on the queue until it is empty, even if other threads drop off additional items to work on in the queue

The hard part was guaranteeing that data doesn't sit in the queue not being worked on in the event that a thread drops off a piece of work around the same time as the work thread is finishing up.

I would assume there exists an abstraction to solve this problem.  Does anybody know of any?

---

Edit:

To be more specific, I am speaking about an incremental search indexer, and the data being added to the queue is additional documents to be processed.  When I'm talking about starting and stopping a group of work, I'm referring to building up a caching context and committing an updated index.  We can't just run a work thread at all times, because if we never commit, the new index never gets committed, and if we don't close the caching context periodically, it can grow too large.

The goal is that most of the time, only a few pieces of work are processed at a time, but during periods of heavy load, we don't waste too much time doing too many commits.

Comment: So there's a high overhead to starting and stopping, but you can add to the current run without additional overhead? So, just never stop your run! :-D Put a busy-wait in there, like `Thread.sleep(500);` perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Java has a lot of concurrency abstractions at http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html

Comment: you need to use a blocking queue.  basically, a thread trying to read from that queue will block until another thread puts something into it.  See the link I provided in my answer for the api and the javadoc.  I would also recommend, reading "Java: Concurrency in Practice" by Brian Goetz

Answer (score 1):

"Only one thread can work on the data at a time" -- This line indicates that you need a semaphore to control how many workers(consumers) can work.

For producer side you will need a blockingqueue so that producer will block(wait) if the list is full before adding to the list.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out the [Disruptor](http://code.google.com/p/disruptor/), an open source project which is all about processing a **lot** of data with **very** low latency, in order, sequentially. I have not used it, personally but it sounds about right for your problem.

Comment: It looks like you need to completely rewrite your code to use this framework, so it's only useful if you __really__ need speed.

Comment: Yes, AFAIK it's a totally different abstraction from a queue. I don't think the actual use case for this question was included when I wrote the answer, and it doesn't sound like low latency or uber-performance is required.